# Can a theory be not satisfiable? Idk if I expressed myself right, can it be that a theory has no model?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

According to lecture on FO logic:
A Σ-theory T is defined by a set of Σ-sentences.

According to another lecture on mathematical logic (predicate logic):
A theory is a satisfiable set T ⊆ FO (τ) of sentences, which is closed under |=, meaning it holds for all τ-sentences ψ with T |= ψ, that ψ ∈ T.

I am asking because of this true/false statement (*): There exists a signature Σ and a Σ-theory T such that no Σ-formulas are T-satisfiable.

A formula is T-satisfiable, if there exists a structure to satisfy both T and this formula.

The statement could be true if the theory is unsatisfiable, meaning it has no model. If the theory has a model that satisfies it, you could pick the formula to be one of the sentences of the theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a theory be not satisfiable?

If you restrict the definition of *theory* to "satisfiable set" of sentences, the answer is NO.

But, in general, we have that a formula (set of formulas) is *unsatisfiable* iff it is inconsistent.

Thus, a single-axiom "theory", like e.g.$\{ \ \forall x (x \ne x) \ \}$ has no model.

Every inconsistent set of sentences is unsatisfiable, i.e. has no model.

---

The "standard" use of [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic)) in logic is:

> a set of sentences in a formal language.

See also David Marker, [Model Theory: An Introduction (Springer, 2002)](https://books.google.it/books?id=3LIPBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA14), page 14:

> Let $\mathcal L$ a language. An $\mathcal L$-*theory* $T$ is simply a set of $\mathcal L$-sentences.

Comment: so basically a Theory in it's default definition is just a set of sentences and doesn't have to have any special properties? So it could as well be an unsatisfiable set?

Comment: i can't share the links directly as you have to be logged in into the learning platform of the university. I could do screenshots but the second definition comes from a script that is in german.

Comment: i also wanted to ask about axioms? are they just sentences in a theory? so no special properties either?

Comment: @Andi - yes. What is Axiomatic Set Theory like e.g. [$\mathsf {ZF}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html)? The theory (in the sense above) "made of" its axioms.